# How to set maximum height and minimum time in unity3d vertical jumping?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am currently studying unity and trying to make a simple game but i cant get the hang on how or what to do to set a fixed height in jumping vertically and jump time. Thank you in advance for the recommendations.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please edit your question with code you have tried and we might be able to help you :)

Answer (score 0):

This could be simple. Jumping would mean traversing the y-axis, therefore your jump height could just be a

```
'Vector3 (this.transform.position.x, this.transform.position.y + 10f, 'this.transform.position.z);
```

you also should add gravity as a downwards force, acting at all times, as a -1 to your sprite's y position constantly.